# Qt gives the wrong screen geometry?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am trying to get the screen resolution from PySide:

```
class Prog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()

        desktop = QtGui.QDesktopWidget()
        dim = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen())
        print(dim)
        print(desktop.width())
        print(desktop.height())
        print(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry())

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
prog = Prog()
prog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am on a macbook pro so I know the resolution is 2560-by-1600, but Qt seems to give the wrong answer consistently:

```
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 22, 1440, 874)
1440
900
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1440, 900)
```

did I do anything wrong here?

Comment: To get correct screen resolution for specific screen in Qt 5 you can use QScreen::devicePixelRatio (it will return value 2.0 for the retina display) and multiply on QScreen width and height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with Qt, you can read this doc: [retina display support](https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11) and mostly this part `Mac OS X High-dpi Support` where you can find:

> The key to the OS X high-dpi mode is that most geometry that was
> previously specified in device pixels are now in device-independent
> points. This includes desktop geometry (which on the 15 inch retina
> MacBook Pro is 1440×900 and not the full 2880×1800), window geometry
> and event coordinates. The CoreGraphics paint engine is aware of the
> full resolution and will produce output at that resolution. For
> example, a 100×100 window occupies the same area on screen on a normal
> and high-dpi screen (everything else being equal). On the high-dpi
> screen the window’s backing store contains 200×200 pixels.

and:

> The main benefits of this mode is backwards compatibility and free
> high-dpi vector graphics. Unaware applications simply continue to work
> with the same geometry as before and can keep hardcoded pixel values.
> At the same time they get crisp vector graphics such as text for free.
> Raster graphics does not get an automatic improvement but is
> manageable. The downside is the inevitable coordinate system confusion
> when working with code that mixes points and pixels.
>
> The scale factor between points and pixels is always 2x. This is also
> true when changing the screen resolution – points and pixels are
> scaled by the same amount. When scaling for “More Space” applications
> will render to a large backing store which is then scaled down to the
> physical screen resolution.

Comment: Link dead. Maybe updated link: https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11